# Need to show that length of module k[x,y]/(x,y) = 1 !?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, modules

I need help to show that the length of $k[x,y] \big / (x,y)$ as a $k[x,y]$-module is $1$, where $k$ is a field and the length defined as the number of submodules we can line up from the trivial set to the base module.

I already tried to create an isomorphism between $k[x,y] \big / (x,y)$ and $k$ but I'm struggling with the fact that $k$ would be seen as a $k[x,y]$-module. I could also just show that every non-trivial submodule of $k[x,y] \big /(x,y)$ contains $1$, but I struggle with writing it.

Please help me I need advice.

Comment: I'm not sure why this got downvoted... OP gave ideas for how one might try to attack this problem, and took note of where exactly in the process they're struggling (namely viewing $k$ as a $k[x,y]$-module). This doesn't seem like a naked problem statement worthy of a downvote to me

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to mse!

You're exactly right that we want to view $k[x,y] \big / (x,y) \cong k$ as a $k[x,y]$-module. The gist of the idea is that $x$ and $y$ both act as $0$. Indeed, if $c \in k$ then we can lift it to an equivalence class $c + (x,y)$ in $k[x,y] \big / (x,y)$. Then if we multiply by $x$, we get $cx + (x,y) = 0 + (x,y)$ (do you see why?). This descends along the isomorphism again to give $x \cdot c = 0$. A similar argument shows $y \cdot c = 0$ for any $c \in k$.

From this information, you can calculate the length directly trying to understand the $k[x,y]$-submodules of $k$ (which are, in particular, $k$-vector spaces), but in the interest of exposing you to more flexible techniques, here's another approach. (there are many tricks for calculating lengths of modules, many of which can be found as theorems in the [stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00IU)).

For this particular example, I'll give a hint. Lemma [10.52.5](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00IX) (at time of writing, though the link will continue working even if the lemma number changes) says that

> If $R \to S$ is a surjection of rings, and $M$ is an $S$-module, then $\text{length}_R(M) = \text{length}_S(M)$

Now we have a surjection $k[x,y] \to k$ sending $x$ and $y$ to $0$, and $k$ is a $k$-module in a natural way.

- What is the length of $k$ as a $k$-module, $\text{length}_k(k)$?
- Do you see how we can use this information (with the lemma above) in order to compute $\text{length}_{k[x,y]}(k)$?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks ! I really like your text and plan to use this lemma in my homework, but I have to prove it and I think the proof on the other website is not rigorous enough, could you explain it a bit more precisely please ?